# nodejs http client stuck on high traffic

Tags: node.js, linux, http, networking, kubernetes

i am encountering weird behavior which i cant explain, i have GKE cluster of 1 instance (2 cpu, 4gb memory) which contain 1 service of nodeJS application with 2 replicas which contain 1 function:

```
        const req = client.get("https://myextrenalapi.com", opts, (res) => {
            let responseBody = ''
            res.socket.setNoDelay();
            res.on('data', (chunk) => { responseBody += chunk })
            res.on('end', () => {
                return responseBody;
            })
        })
```

now after starting to loadtest this server with approx 130 RPS it starts to get slow and http client request takes 10+ seconds (300ms idle).

BUT when i try to CURL from within one of my nodes (while doing the stress test) to:
https://myextrenalapi.com
the requests takes 300MS, so how come curl is doing it in 300MS while to nodeJS http client it takes 10+ seconds?

i added logging to the http client while running the stress test:

```
{"dnsLookup":194,"tcpConnection":6875,"tlsHandshake":9206,"firstByte":10746,"end":10746}
```

any ideas why its so slow campers to CURL on highload?
i tried almost everything in nodeJS side, i changed maxTcpConnection, keep-alive, removed agent completely but results are almost the same in all senarios

Comment: Performance analysis is complex at the best of times, but to start with `responseBody += chunk` is probably bad. Replace that with an array append and join them all the end. Will cut down on the number of reallocs and memcpys.

Comment: Were you still getting similar `tcpConnection` and `tlsHandshake` values when using a common agent with keep-alive? What library are you using? How big is the avg response size? What kind of load is myexternalapi.com capable of?

Comment: What do you do with responsebody after this? It currently gets swallowed

Comment: getting same results with tcpConnection/tlsHandshake with keep-alive on/off my response is the loadtestresults:
{"dnsLookup":194,"tcpConnection":6875,"tlsHandshake":9206,"firstByte":10746,"end":10746} - myexternalapi.com is capable of over 5k rps